Question about DAO Factory Architecture & Proposal Management
I'm building a DAO builder and need feedback on my factory contract architecture.
Architecture Overview: Planning to have a factory contract that deploys:
1. Proxy contract
2. Implementation contract
3. Treasury contract
4. ERC20 token contract
5. Initialize proxy with implementation, treasury, and token addresses

Proposal & Treasury System:
- On-chain storage: Only storing proposal IDs and execution status
- Treasury can only be controlled by DAO contract through passed proposals
- All fund movements require successful proposal execution
- Treasury will be deployed with immutable DAO address
- DAO implementation updates will only be possible through proposals with quorum votes

Questions:

Is this deployment pattern feasible through a single factory contract?
What issues should I watch out for with this architecture?
Are there any security concerns with having the DAO contract as sole controller of treasury?
What's the best way to handle initialization to ensure all contracts are properly linked?

Main Concerns:
- Contract initialization order
- Security of multiple contract deployments and initializations
- Best practices for upgradeability with multiple contracts
- The reason for proxy pattern is future DAO functionality upgrades.

Would appreciate insights from anyone who has built similar systems. Thanks!
